# How to remove hidden field associated with checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am using ASP.net MVC. I am posting multiple checkboxes as array to controller using name attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]"id="@model.count">
<label for="@("model.count)"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="checkboxes[]" value="0" />
```

I want to send value "on" when checkbox is checked and 0 when not checked.
So in javascript, I have done below code.

```
        $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
        // set value 0 
        $(this).attr('checked', true).val(0);
     });

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {          
        $(this).next('input["type=hidden"]').remove();             
    });
```

But it's not working. Hidden field is not getting removed for checked checkboxes. I want to send array whose length is equal to no of checkboxes only.(and not hidden field).
How should I do that?

Comment: You can try `$(this).next().next()`

Comment: or try : `$(this).nextAll('input[type=hidden]:first').remove()` ?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem - how are you "sending values"?  The hidden field should not be included when the checkbox is ticked and will be included (using its value) when the checkbox is not ticked.  So by "ticking" (`.attr('checked', true)`) your checkboxes, you're bypassing that built-in functionality.

Comment: @freedomn-m , I  had tried by removing javascript part also but it did not work. It was still sending double values for checked checkboxes.

Comment: *What* was sending double values?  "it"?